# Convert Quickbooks IPP API from legacy QBD v3 to QBO

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

We have built a working integration between our web app and quickbooks desktop using the legacy quickbooks API v3 for QBD (https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_legacy/qbd_v3).

We now want to add a new adapter to our web app to support the new QBO api (https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0050_quickbooks_api).

The c# SDK (https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0500_developer_kits/0010.net_tools) for QBO seems to be the same one as we are currently using for QBD. Is that true?

What changes do I need to make from our current QBD adapter to get it work with QBO? i.e. when using the C# SDK what are the differences when using it for QBD vs QBO?

For example, it seems that when you create a ServiceContext, you specify the data source as either IntuitServicesType.QBD or IntuitServicesType.QBO. Is it simply that easy or what other changes would I need to make...here are my additional thoughts on potential changes I may or may not have to do:

1. Do I need to create a new App in the Intuit App center for this new
   version of connecting? Or can I continue to use the existing Intuit
   App we created for the QBD interface?
2. I believe the supported entities and formats (properties) of those
   entities are different, but if the SDKs are the same and hence I
   have the same references in each of my 2 projects (QBD adapter and
   QBO adapter), both referencing Intuit.Ipp.Data. Then the entities
   are the same such as Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer. So is the Customer
   entity the same for both QBD and QBO, but on the backend when you
   import a customer into the QBO files you do it differently based on
   if the destination is QBD or QBO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer in Intuit's Live community for your question-
https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1233347-help-with-convert-from-legacy-qbd-v3-to-qbo